# cant install pytest on macOs High sierra

Tags: pytest

so now the installation is done, it doesnt detect that it is installed, it tells me pytest command no found
Here is the command:

```
pytest --version
```

Here is the error:

```
Mostafas-MacBook-Pro:bin mostafa.osama2$ pip install --user -U pytest
Collecting pytest
  Downloading pytest-3.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (184kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 4.0MB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: pluggy<0.7,>=0.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytest)
Requirement already up-to-date: attrs>=17.2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytest)
Requirement already up-to-date: py>=1.5.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytest)
Requirement already up-to-date: funcsigs; python_version < "3.0" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytest)
Collecting setuptools (from pytest)
  Downloading setuptools-38.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 2.4MB/s 
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from pytest)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, six, pytest
Successfully installed pytest-3.3.1 setuptools-38.2.4 six-1.11.0
Mostafas-MacBook-Pro:bin mostafa.osama2$ pytest --version
-bash: pytest: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the explanation at the top of the output:

> The directory '/Users/mostafa.osama2/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory '/Users/mostafa.osama2/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The first thing to do is to change change those directories back to your user, likely using:

```
chown -R mostafa.osama2 /Users/mostafa.osama2/Library/Caches/pip
```

Then you need to decide how you likely want to install the module in your local application, or in your home directory instead. Unless you want the module to be visible system-wide, you can do:

```
pip install --user -U pytest
```

Comment: Thx for ur help , but now I have another problem, the installation worked , but when I try to check the version of pytest , it tells me command not found, I think its because I have python 2.7 and python 3.6 installed at the same time there is some kind of confusion , here is the command line stuff..

Comment: I will update the out on the original post because I cant post it in the comments